# How to get a string to relate to a specific value in an array in Python3

Tags: arrays, string, python-3.x

What I am trying to do is have a program that will take a word, and get the numeric values associated with each letter, so a is 1, b is 2 and so forth.

What I have done so far is made an array for the alphabet and sliced the input word into strings of 1 letter each.

```
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

and this

```
word = input("""Give me a word
""")

let1 = word[1:1]
let2 = word[2:2]
let3 = word[3:3]
let4 = word[4:4]
let5 = word[5:5]
let6 = word[6:6]
let7 = word[7:7]
let8 = word[8:8]
```

Comment: Are the numeric values arbitrary (that is, 'a' could be 42), or is it always in the numerical position in the alphabet ('a' is always 1, 'b' is always 2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do like this,

```
>>> s = input("""Give me a word
""")
Give me a word
foobar
>>> alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
>>> n = range(1,27)
>>> zip(alphabet, n)
>>> d = dict(zip(alphabet, n))
>>> ' '.join(str(d[i]) for i in s)
'6 15 15 2 1 18'
```

You could define a separate function.

```
def assonum(s):
    alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
    n = range(1,27)
    d = dict(zip(alphabet, n))
    print(' '.join(str(d[i]) for i in s))

assonum(input("""Give me a word\n"""))
```

**sample output:**

```
Give me a word
abcxyz
1 2 3 24 25 26
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried building a function? Probably the simplest method would be to use a function and for loops.

```
def word_numbers(word): # define a function that takes a word
    alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    word_array = [] # initialize a empty list

    # loop through the word
    for i in word: 
        # loop through the range of 0 to the length of the alphabet
        for j in range(0, len(alphabet)):
            # if the characters match append the number to the list
            if i == alphabet[j]:
                word_array.append(j)
                # after a match there is no need to continue through
                # the alphabet. Call break to jump to the next letter in word.
                break
    return(word)
```

Usage:

```
>>> word_numbers("test")
[19, 4, 18, 19]
```

or

```
>>> word_numbers(input("Give me a word: "))
```

The key part being the first `for` loop automatically takes on each character of word sequentially on each iteration of the loop, while the second `for` loop takes on each number in the range of 0 to the length of the the alphabet. Then all you have to do is index out the letter in the alphabet you are currently on with `alphabet[j]`, test equality between the characters by comparing `i` and `alphabet[j]`, and append the number to the list if the characters match. If this doesn't make sense, just comment below and I'll edit.